# Adding elements to list of class in xamarin forms from user input

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have this class :

```
public class Player
    {
        public int PlayerID { get; set; }
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
        public string PlayerTime { get; set; }
        public int PlayerRank { get; set; }

    }
```

And this list containing the player class

```
public List<Player> PlayersTable { get; set; }
 PlayersTable = new List<Player>();
```

the values for player class members will come from different sources :
PlayerName will come from user input "Entry" in xaml - PlayerID will be generated - PlayerTime will come from stopwatch - PlayerRank will come from comparing the best time

**the question is :** how to add all Player data from different sources to the list?
I know that hard coding done by the following code :

```
PlayersTable = new List<Player>();
            {
                new Player()
                {
                    PlayerID = 1,
                    PlayerName = "Yasir",
                    PlayerRank = 1,
                    PlayerTime = "11"
                },
                new Player()
                {
                    PlayerID = 1,
                    PlayerName = "Ahmed",
                    PlayerRank = 2,
                    PlayerTime = "13"
                }
```

but how to add it from sources (like PlayerName will come from user input by xaml Entry : `<Entry Text="{Binding PlayerName}"/>` .. And the PlayerTime will come from
(timer.Elapsed) for Timer , thanks

Comment: your entry is already bound to `PlayerName`, so you will get that value from the `PlayerName` property of your model.  You will have to write a function to calculate PlayerRank.  It is unclear how PlayerTime is triggered.  There isn't really enough information here to provide a concrete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you to use `ObservableCollection<Player>` to replace `List<Player>`, because [ObservableCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0)  represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Then I do one simple that you can take a look:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="PlayerName :" />
        <Entry x:Name="entry1" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btnadd"
            Command="{Binding addcommand}"
            Text="add data" />

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PlayersTable}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding PlayerName}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding PlayerTime}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding PlayerRank}" />

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page25 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Player> PlayersTable { get; set; }
    public Command addcommand { get; }
    public Page25()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PlayersTable = new ObservableCollection<Player>()
        {
             new Player() {PlayerID = 1, PlayerName = "Yasir", PlayerRank = 1, PlayerTime = "11" },
             new Player() {PlayerID = 1, PlayerName = "Ahmed", PlayerRank = 2, PlayerTime = "13" }
        };

        //add one test data to test.
        addcommand = new Command(()=> {
            Player player = new Player();
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry1.Text))
            {
                player.PlayerName = entry1.Text;
                //get PlayerID by method.
                player.PlayerID = 0;
                //get PlayerTime by method or you can also get value from stopwatch.Don't know how do you use stopwatch.
                player.PlayerTime = "test";
                //get PlayerRank by method.
                player.PlayerRank = 0;
                PlayersTable.Add(player);
            }          
        
        });
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
 
   
}
```

Comment: I want to accept your answer and the other answer , all works to me FYI thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the rest of your code looks like, but assuming you want to add a new player when you enter the player's name into Entry, you will need to add a command to run when the user presses the return key.

```
<Entry Text="{Binding PlayerName}" ReturnCommand="{Binding CommandComplete}"></Entry>
```

and then implement that command in your ViewModel where you have an instance of the list of players:

```
public partial class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<Player> PlayersTable { get; set; }
        private int PlayerID { get; set; }
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
        private string PlayerTime { get; set; }
        private int PlayerRank { get; set; } 

        public System.Windows.Input.ICommand CommandComplete { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            PlayersTable = new List<Player>();

            CommandComplete = new Command(() => 
                {
                    PlayerID = GeneratePlayerID(); // assuming you implemented something like this
                    PlayerRank = GetPlayerRank(); // assuming you implemented something like this
                    PlayerTime = GetPlayerTime(); // assuming you implemented something like this
                    Player player = new Player()
                    {
                        PlayerID = this.PlayerID,
                        PlayerName = this.PlayerName,
                        PlayerRank = this.PlayerRank,
                        PlayerTime = this.PlayerTime
                    };
                    PlayersTable.Add(player);
                }
            );
        }

      // the rest of the implementation of MyViewModel
    }
```

Comment: I want to accept your answer and the other answer , all works to me

Comment: According to the rules of of Stack Overflow, you should accept "one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem." So, whichever from those two is the best one for you, you can accept that one, you can not accept both.